# Site payment widgets

Tags: usability

My company offers several dozen services and lately I have been seeing these widgets come about to give them the ability to drop products into an existing client site.

Let's say you are on a branded, hotel site. You select your hotel room, bed and preferences. You now have an image of the room, price and preferences in front of you with a button that says 'book now'. You click and it takes you to another page on the site with a little bit different looking framed-in widget to take your payment info. Same URL and all, but the widget is a little obvious it is not native to the site itself. What do you do? Bail, continue and trust, question, read more?

I have been advocating for a streamlined experience, but it takes a lot of push. Are there significant pros or cons (research appreciated) associated with these site framed-in widgets?

Comment: It'll be great to see some screenshots of these framed-in widgets compare to the rest of the site design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no reason why one should not push for a superior user experience. In fact theres this story that Steve Jobs asked Google's VC if he could change Google's logo to suit iPhone's.

Thats why we have Human Interface Guidelines for Apple App store submission, to ensure users don't have to accept a new UI paradigm

below is a excerpt from an rather old document (from 1990!) by a Carnegie Mellon University's author, [link](http://reports-archive.adm.cs.cmu.edu/anon/itc/CMU-ITC-101.pdf)

"Users also develop a mental model of the system. The user's mental model is modified and refined as the user becomes more familiar with the system. In fact, a well-developed mental
model may eventually enable users to predict system behavior as they continue to explore and learn about the system.
Unfortunately, an application's user interface does not always successfully convey the developer's mental model to users of the application. A user whose mental model of the system is inconsistent with that of the developer may find the application confusing and difficult to use"

Googling "importance of Human interface guidelines" could help for research